# SQL Date Conversion Query

Tags: sql, db2, date-conversion

TimeStamp is a numeric datatype field in my table R for example: 2445302102010 (02/10/2010)
I am trying to query by a date range of 02/09/15 - 02/15/15, the problem is I am getting results from 2010?

```
Select distinct
            R.CID,
            RIGHT(R.TimeStamp,8)
            from TableRev R 
            WHERE
            R.Codes in ('NY','NV') 
            AND RIGHT(R.TimeStamp,8) between 02092015 and 02152015
            ORDER BY R.TimeStamp
```

Comment: First and foremost, if it's a date, it needs to be classified as the correct datatype.  This scenario is exactly why.  What is the '24453' at the beginning?  If that length is always the same you could use the `SUBSTRING` function to parse the actual 'dates' out of it.

Comment: Why, why, why is "timestamp" a numeric type?

Comment: ALPHABETICALLY `02012000` is before `02012100` is before `02022000`. It's the beginning of the STRING the counts. Use datatypes and you won't have this issue.

Comment: I have no control over the way the data was setup in the DB, I'm a business analyst just querying the data..

Comment: If you can't fix the structure you're going to have to parse out the date elements individually, build a date out of it and compare to that.

Comment: And why, why, why is the hours/minutes/seconds (whatever that 24453 is), then the date, then the month and then the year? There's a reason why ISO and ANSI sat around the table and after several months (or years) of discussion decided for the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format (for inserting, etc. I 150% agree that dates and times should be stored with the appropriate datatype.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the date in a way that will allow you to look for a specific date range. For that, [`CONCAT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000781.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-25) (or || : [|| can be used as a synonym for CONCAT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html%23d18872e137?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-10) [see Note 19]) will be helpful. So you can try something like this :

```
Select distinct
        R.CID,
        RIGHT(R.TimeStamp,8)
        from TableRev R 
        WHERE
        R.Codes in ('NY','NV') 
        AND (RIGHT(R.TimeStamp,4) || LEFT(RIGHT(R.TimeStamp,8),4)) 
                        between '20150209' and '20150215'
        ORDER BY R.TimeStamp
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you've run into a problem that I run into all the time. Some programmer a long time ago thought that it would be a good idea....
You're going to have to pull that data in, and convert it to a function that SQL will understand.

Assuming you are using a SQL engine to query a convert will work:
Try this:

```
AND CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(R.TimeStamp,8),101) between 02/09/2015 and 02/15/2015
```

If you are using some DB2 tool you will have to CAST the data, if the original data is formatted correctly. Check the FILELAY to see if the field is in this chart.  [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmstcastdt.htm)  Has to pretty much be an VARCHAR or TIMESTAMP to Cast. If it is, you can:

```
AND CAST(TimeStamp as Date)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a `CONVERT` function in DB2.

Comment: I am pretty sure that iSeries SQL supports the function depending on the version. Guess I should have asked what they are using to run the query.

Comment: Thank you Carl, it looks like I am able to use the convert function (I am using Toad) but I am getting an error that states SQL0206 - Column DATETIME not in specified tables?

Comment: @Carl -- would you mind providing a link? Can't see it in any of the manuals. Also, the date literals in your example don't look right.

Comment: Here are some links... [MS SQL Convert Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) I also like to use this website, [SQL USA](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) They have a lot of great examples written out in plain English, well, as plain as you can get in SQL.